# What is an alternative to Visual Studio for SSIS development?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

To my knowledge, Visual Studio with SSDT is the only development environment for SSIS package development (I don't count editing the XML directly as that is impractical). When it comes to SSIS development, Visual Studio is bloated and buggy to say the least. It constantly freezes, crashes, or does any number of odd things that create hours of debugging and wasted time.

Is there an alternative (practical) development environment for SSIS development?

Answer (score 1):

No, not particularly.

There is [BimlStudio](https://www.varigence.com/BimlStudio) which allows you to take a different approach to designing and implementing standards across your SSIS packages. Love it, would love for people to buy it as the folks that built it are super sharp and make my SSIS development easier.

Ultimately though, the work cycle is design in Biml, emit assets (makes SSIS packages) and then running/testing is still going to be VS.